# How to reread a file by its size?

Tags: python, file

if I want to write a loop using list to determine whether to read a file again, how can I do?
For example
I use

```
f.seek(0,2) 
f.tell()
```

to know about the size of file is 3
If I want to output

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
f is "abc"
f.read(a[0]) is "a"
f.read(a[2]) is "abc"
f.read(a[3]) is "abca" 
f.read(a[4]) is "abcab"
```

how to write if/else to determine this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read the file repeatedly. Just read it once, and duplicate the contents as many times as you need it.

Try to read the number of characters that you want. If the file is shorter than this, you'll get a shorter result. Calculate how many times to repeat that by dividing the desired length by the length that was returned. And use modulus to calculate how many additional characters to take from the result.

```
def read_n(f, n):
    temp = f.read(n)
    if len(temp) == n:
        return temp
    count = n // len(temp)
    remainder = n % len(temp)
    result = temp * count + temp[:remainder]
    return result
```

Comment: but how to continue read when the file reach the end? what should I write?

Comment: Why do you need to continue reading? The example you showed said that you want to go back to the beginning. This does it by simply duplicating the string.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like the Unix `tail -f` command, which waits for the file to grow and shows the new contents?

Comment: Nope, but I want to know how to use count and remainder given in your function. I do not quite understand how to read multiple times and connect strings together

Comment: It's not reading multiple times. It's just reading once, and then duplicating it as many times as needed.